# D3 Queue Only Produces Error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm excited to use d3 to help me process some data but I'm having some trouble loading my data.

My .csv looks like this:

```
id,name,city,latitude,longitude,dpcapacity,online_date
456,2112 W Peterson Ave,Chicago,41.991178,-87.683593,15,2/10/2015 14:04:42
```

My .js looks like this:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.csv, "/data/2017_Q1Q2/Stations.csv")
  .await(analyze);

function analyze(error, stations) {
  if(error) console.log("error", error);
}
```

And then my error is this:

*Error is {id: "456", name: "2112 W Peterson Ave", city: "Chicago", latitude: "41.991178", longitude: "-87.683593", …}*

What is the error in my .csv file? Why is the csv data correctly being turned to object but there is an error popping up with the first element of the data?

I appreciate anyone's help. Obviously I want to load more than one file but I'm just starting with one for now.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the module that I was following is deprecated. I found it from an old but still sort of helpful tutorial (found [here](http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html)) is deprecated as of D3 5.0. Instead, use [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) instead.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. The fact that D3 v5 doesn't use XHR anymore has nothing to do with your problem. Besides that, D3 v4 is not deprecated, d3.queue is still working just fine: it makes no sense saying that a JS library is deprecated, you could even use D3 v2 as long as you reference it. You certainly are not using D3 v5, because your code would produce a *"d3.queue is not a function"* error. Finally, D3 v5 has not even been released, it's still a RC.

Answer (score 0):

d3-queue expects the functions that it calls - like `d3.csv` in this instance - to call their callbacks with arguments of `(error, result)`. As you can see from the [d3.dsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#csv) documentation, it doesn't follow that pattern: if you provide a callback, it's called per row, and with the row as the first argument, not an error.

If you really want to use d3.queue - if, for instance, you intend to use its currency support - you might need to do something like

```
function getcsv(url, cb) {
  d3.csv(url).then(res => cb(null, res)).catch(cb);
}
```

In order to make d3.csv to act like d3-queue expects. But if you *don't* need concurrency support (which is most likely the case), look into using `Promise.all` instead: it'll also let you process lots of files and reliably wait until they're all done, and it will work more smoothly with functions like d3.csv that return promises.